# Azure ML Studio Pipeline InvalidDatasetError: Dataset contains invalid data, failed to load _meta.yaml

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

I'm playing with Azure ML Studio pipelines and unfortunately I can not success any of pipeline run because of following error:

`InvalidDatasetError: Dataset contains invalid data, failed to load _meta.yaml`

See screenshot below:

[image]

I'm using a tabular dataset created from file. It looks like it's parsed correctly:

[image]

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: See if the data is archived or not ?

Comment: what if you will try a dataset which will not contain special symbols like `Ż, ż` which I see on screenshot? Even if it was parsed correctly by AML UI it does not mean it will be accepted without transformations by next steps in your pipeline.